# How can I figure out what colors I have in this code?

Tags: colors, hex, arago

I'm working on a TI AM335x EVM. It uses the Arago Linux distribution.

Now I want to modify the splash screen for this device, it has a user space application called [psplash](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/psplash/), and there is a file which defines colors, here's the code in that file:

psplash-colors.h:

```
/* This is the overall background color */
#define PSPLASH_BACKGROUND_COLOR 0xec,0xec,0xe1

/* This is the color of any text output */
#define PSPLASH_TEXT_COLOR 0x6d,0x6d,0x70

/* This is the color of the progress bar indicator */
#define PSPLASH_BAR_COLOR 0x6d,0x6d,0x70

/* This is the color of the progress bar background */
#define PSPLASH_BAR_BACKGROUND_COLOR 0xec,0xec,0xe1
```

I get these are hex codes making up RGB values, and based on the fact it's 3 sets of bytes I thought they might have been [x11 color codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names).

What I'm trying to figure out is exactly what colors these are, for example I can't find `0xEC 0xEC 0xE1` anywhere. How can I figure out what colors these values represent?

Answer (score 2):

0x before a number means that it is written in hexadecimal , so you just convert the hex number to decimal and you get the standard 0-255 rgb values

```
0xec,0xec,0xe1  ->  ec,ec,e1  -> 236,236,225
0x6d,0x6d,0x70  ->  6d,6d,70  -> 109,109,112
```

[here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html) is a nice hex to decimal converted ,in case you are not good in math

and [here](http://www.color-hex.com) is value to color converter ,just put the value of the color in the textfield and the color should appear

Answer (score 0):

These values are in hexadecimal.
If i convert them to decimal and put them in a drawing application i get a color.
for exemple: 
0xEC 0xEC 0xE1 -> 236,236,225 -> I get a light grey